# Should I be using toPromise in rxjs6? What does it do?

Tags: deprecated, rxjs6

I'm having a little trouble reading the rxjs documentation.

As far as I can see, this is the official documentation: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api

In the [Observable documenation page](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/Observable) under methods it has listed `lift()` and `subscribe()`, though later down the page, under examples, there are `forEach()`, `pipe()`, and `toPromise()`.

None of those have usage notes - just argument specifiers.

Looking at this page: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html

We're told:

> :warning: toPromise has been deprecated! (RxJS 5.5+)

How I am I meant to be reading this? `toPromise` was deprecated in 5.5x and continues to be deprecated?

Answer (score 5):

**TLDR;** I think the documentation is incorrect.

**`toPromise` is not deprecated.**

Apparently there was some issue when `toPromise` was moved to `operators` and then removed in 5.5 beta.

> toPromise was only available in rxjs/operators during a beta of 5.5. It was removed because it doesn't make any sense, it's not an operator, it's a method of subscription that results in a promise.
>   [See GH issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3482#issuecomment-377451405)

Also there is no deprecation notice in the [sources](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts#L329-L343) and none in the [migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#deprecations). Rxjs team is pretty reliable about deprecation warnings.

I think the documentation at https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html is either wrong or it's referring to `toPromise` as operator - which has been removed.